# Counting occurances of character in strings

Tags: javascript

I made a function that counts the occurances of x's and o's in a given string and returns true if they are equal.

```
function ExOh(str) { 
  var x_count = 0;
  var o_count = 0;

  for (var i = 0;i < str.length-1;i++){
    if (str[i] === 'x'){
      x_count = x_count + 1;
    }
    else if (str[i] === 'o'){
      o_count = o_count + 1;
    }
  }

  console.log(o_count);
  console.log(x_count);
  if (x_count === o_count){
    return true;}
  else{
    return false;
  }

}
// keep this function call here 
// to see how to enter arguments in JavaScript scroll down
ExOh(readline());
```

I added the lines of code

```
  console.log(o_count);
  console.log(x_count);
```

To see if it was counting correctly and I discovered that was the issue. After testing it I realized that this function is not testing the last element in the string. I tried changing the length of the for loop, but I can't think of what else could be wrong.

Any advice?

Thanks mates

Comment: for condition `i < str.length-1` is wrong it's `i < str.length`

Comment: Or use regex to make oStr and xStr with only o's end x's.
Then compare o.length with x.length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript arrays are 0 index based objects. So, your loop should be like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
```

otherwise the last element will be skipped.

Consider that the length of the string is `5`. So, `i` starts from 0 and if you had your original condition

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i++) {
```

following are the comparisons happening in the loop

```
0 < 4
1 < 4
2 < 4
3 < 4
4 < 4 -- Fails
```

So it breaks out of the loop. But the last element will be at index 4. But when you have the condition like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
```

the comparisons go like this

```
0 < 5
1 < 5
2 < 5
3 < 5
4 < 5
5 < 5 -- Fails
```

It breaks out of the loop only after comparing all the elements.

So, your actual program can be written like this

```
function ExOh(str) {
    var x_count = 0, o_count = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] === 'x') {
            x_count = x_count + 1;
        } else if (str[i] === 'o') {
            o_count = o_count + 1;
        }
    }

    return x_count === o_count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is running one too short. Try this instead.

```
  for (var i = 0;i < str.length;i++){
    if (str[i] === 'x'){
      x_count = x_count + 1;
    }
    else if (str[i] === 'o'){
      o_count = o_count + 1;
    }
  }
```

Comment: not "too long". it's running not long enough, actually.

Answer (score 0):

alternate method to count characters:

```
var s = 'example';
s.split('').filter(function (i) { return i === 'e'; }).length; // 2
```

Comment: If you're doing this, why not `s.split('e').length - 1` ?

Comment: because it was to simple :) +1 for that one

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping over the whole *String* with `for`, I'd see if using `indexOf` achieves a faster result

```
function countOccurance(haystack, needle) {
    var total = 0, pos = -1;
    while (-1 !== (pos = haystack.indexOf(needle, pos + 1)))
        total += 1;
    return total;
}
```

Then

```
var x_count = countOccurance(str, 'x'),
    o_count = countOccurance(str, 'o');

return x_count === o_count;
```

---

**EDIT** looks like I might have been wrong about it being faster! [**jsperf**](http://jsperf.com/count-chars-index-vs-split-vs-for)

```
function indexOfMethod(haystack, needle) {
    var total = 0, pos = -1;
    while (-1 !== (pos = haystack.indexOf(needle, pos + 1)))
        total += 1;
    return total;
}
function splitMethod(haystack, needle) {
    return haystack.split(needle).length - 1;
}
function forMethod(haystack, needle) {
    var total = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < haystack.length; ++i)
        if (haystack.charAt(i) === needle)
            total += 1;
    return total;
}
```

The `forMethod` will only work with *char* `needle`, whereas the other two should work with any *String* as `needle`, if that matters.

Comment: Ugh. Why use `if (someBoolean) { return true; } return false;`, when `return (something)` is quite enough?

Comment: @raina77ow yep, I copied it and didn't simplify down enough, edited

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in `for` loop. Try changing to this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
```

If you want to avoid using for loops, you can use this much shorter version of `ExOh` function.

```
function ExOh(str) { 
  return str.match(/o/g).length == str.match(/x/g).length
}
```